# Using grep -Einvw "regexp" to find lines with words starting with certain characters?

Tags: regex, grep

I'm fairly new to using grep, and would like to find lines that contain at least two words starting with "go". Also, to determine if a word has ended, it must be followed be a space, a period, a comma, or a semicolon.

The solution I have come up with is as follows:

```
grep -Ein " go[a-z]*[ .,;].* go[a-z]*[ .,;]" file.txt
```

This is returning three results that match my criteria, but I know that there are four possible solutions. Could anyone please give some advice?

Comment: What is the fourth (unmatched) line?

Comment: I'm not sure what it is, I only know that there are four results.

Comment: How do you know there are four results?

Comment: In the exercise I am trying to complete, the hint provided was there should be four results.

Comment: How do you expect to write code to print specific lines if you can't figure out which lines you want to print from a given sample input file? How will we know if a potential answer is right or wrong? Any given wrong answer might print 4 lines from your input file, and they may or may not be the same 4 lines that the right answer would print. THINK about the problem and then provide concise, testable sample input and expected output so we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Gnu grep supports `\b` for "word boundary", you probably want to use that at the start of the first word, since that also matches at the beginning of line. (Your current regexp requires that both words are preceded by a space.)

Answer (score 0):

The answer from Bass is correct.
Here is a possible solution, to detect such a line:

```
\bgo\w*\b.*\bgo\w*\b
```

If you want it case-insensitive (will match words like "GoPro" or "GOAL"):

```
\b[gG][oO]\w*\b.*\b[gG][oO]\w*\b
```

Depending on the words you are expecting, if you want to match also special word-chars like "é" you cal always add it:

```
\b[gG][oO][\wéÉ]*\b.*\b[gG][oO][\wéÉ]*\b
```

Note: The match will not return the whole line, just test if it is a match.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job:

```
grep -Ein '\bgo.*\bgo' file.txt
```

**Explanation:**

```
\b  : word boundary, makes sure we don't have any letter before
go  : literally "go"
.*  : 0 or more any character
\b  : word boundary, makes sure we don't have any letter before
go  : literally "go"
```

With file.txt:

```
goabc xyz go def
goabc xyz defgo
goabc xyz go def
```

It gives:

```
1:goabc xyz go def
3:goabc xyz go def
```